# Check if instance of python class has attribute without instantiating the class

Tags: python, attributes, instance

Is it possible to check if an instance of a class has an attribute without (being able to) instantiating the class?

**Example:**

class `A` where I lack knowledge about arguments to instantiate:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, unkown):
        self.a = 1
```

checking for attribute a in class A fails:

```
hasattr(A,'a')
>> False
```

checking for attribute a in instance of class `A` would succeed:

```
hasattr(A(1),'a')
>> True
```

Is it possible to check for attribute `a` without instantiating `A`? Maybe with something different than `hasattr`?

Comment: Not possible without changes to your class in any sane way. Depending on context you might want to use a dataclass and then access `__dataclass_fields__`.

Comment: self.a is an attribute of an instance of the class and therefore never exists until its class is constructed. A class attribute however can be detected by examination of the class's __dict__ (or with hasattr) without instantiation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this is not possible. You can freely set any attribute on any instance of `A` at any time. Consider

```
a = A('foo')
setattr(a, input('attr_name: '), 'bar')
```

`A` cannot know what attributes may or may not be set on its instances in the future.

You could do some insane things like parse `__init__` if you want to limit the question to attributes set in `__init__`, but most likely we're having an XY-problem here.

Comment: So the only way is making `a` a property, right?

Comment: @gustavz how about documenting the class? Why do you need to dynamically infer instance attributes at runtime? Regardless of that, going through properties seems valid, but remember that properties and attributes can be deleted from instances at runtime.

Comment: @gustavz Adding a property decorator won't help

Comment: the background that we have a pretty wild testing framework mock patching attributes, which works for properties but doesn't for instance attributes.
I am looking for a way to check if an instance attribute exists to be able to patch it.

Comment: @gustavz an instance attribute, by definition, cannot exist until there is an instance of the class. Even then, remember that instance attributes can come into being outside of \_\_init\_\_ so you're really asking the impossible

Comment: Follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72629673/python-mock-patch-class-instance-attribute

Answer (score 0):

As it's not possible, a workaround can be making `a` a property:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, unkown):
        self._a = 1
    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a
        
hasattr(A,'a')
>> True
```

Just leaving this here in the sense of completeness

Comment: This is ambiguous. hasattr is returning True because it sees a function called 'a'. It doesn't know what the purpose of the function is. Try removing the property decorator and you'll see that hasattr will still return True

Comment: correct, but as it has the sole purpose of returning `_a` it does what I want implicitly

Comment: I could construct an example where this fails your purpose, but it would be pretty contrived.

Comment: If you want to make this more robust, subclass `property` (e.g. `my_attribute_property`) and then inspect `A` for these kinds of properties.

Comment: yes that's probably true but my use case is really as simple as this. So this might not be globally true but worth a try in such cases.

Comment: the property is defined at class level so your answer is nice turn-around about the orginal problem... but now you should test it with `isinstance(A.a, property)`