# Python mock.patch class instance attribute

Tags: python, mocking, attributes, instance

Is it possible to patch an instance attribute of a class with only a path string and **not** directly by importing the class and using `mock.patch.object`

**Example:**

`file.py`

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
```

`test_file.py`

instead of

```
import mock
from file import A

@mock.patch.object(A, 'a', 2)
def test_a(self):
    print(A.a)
```

something like

```
import mock

@mock.patch("config.A.a", return_value=2)
def test_a(self):
    print(A.a)
```